# Have problem using export function in node js

Tags: node.js, pug, nodemailer

**The code for pug.compiler.js is:**

```
/**
 * Pug Utilities
 */
 const {compileFile} =require('pug');
 /**
  * 
  * @param {String} relativeTemplatePath Pug template name
  * @param {Object} [data] Object
  * @returns {String} HTML
  */
 export function compile(relativeTemplatePath, data){
     let absoluteTemplatePath = process.cwd() + '/src/views/' + relativeTemplatePath + '.pug';
     let compiledTemplate = compileFile(absoluteTemplatePath)(data);
     return compiledTemplate;
 };
```

**The error is :**

```
 export function compile(relativeTemplatePath, data){
 ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ProgramData\projects\nodejs\whatsapp\test\app.js:11:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
```

**So I have a problem understanding how do I use this export function. I think it should work right?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is NodeJS considers module by default as [CommonJS Modules](https://medium.com/@cgcrutch18/commonjs-what-why-and-how-64ed9f31aa46#:%7E:text=CommonJS%20is%20a%20module%20formatting,heavily%20influenced%20NodeJS%27s%20module%20management.).

So instead of `export` you should use `module.exports`, or if you're using NodeJS v13+ you can enable ES Modules by either:

- Changing the extension of your file to `mjs`
- Adding `"type": "module"` property to your `package.json`

Using `module.exports` should be like:

```
function compile(relativeTemplatePath, data){
     let absoluteTemplatePath = process.cwd() + '/src/views/' + relativeTemplatePath + '.pug';
     let compiledTemplate = compileFile(absoluteTemplatePath)(data);
     return compiledTemplate;
 };

module.exports = {compile};
```

Comment: ``` module.exports function compile(relativeTemplatePath, data) ```                                 
 This should work right but it  shows an error at function. Why?

Comment: Ok, my bad, I didn't mean to literally replace the word `export` with `module.exports`, I mean to you the feature. It should be `module.exports = {compile}` AFTER you defined the function, at the end of your file